# ¿Como puedo meter y sacar variables con "session" con java:?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web, session

este es el escenario:

Por un  lado tengo un .java donde quiero meter una variable en session haciendo esto:

```
String [] matriz = new String[5];

matriz[0] = "Hola";

matriz[1] = "que";

matriz[2] = "tal";

matriz[3] = "estas";

request.getSession().setAttribute("Resultado", matriz);
```

Por otra parte tengo un .jsp donde quiero recogerlo e imprimirlo usando esto:

(El código está metido como corresponde <% *Codigo* %>

```
String[] mensaje = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("Resultado"); 

        if(mensaje == null) out.println("No se ha podido recuperar el mensaje de la sesion.");

        else{

            for(int i = 0; i < mensaje.length; i++){

                out.println(mensaje[i]); 
            }
        }
```

Sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto me dice que "mensaje" el atributo donde intento recuperar la matriz del session es "null".

¿Sabríais decirme donde estoy equivocado?

Gracias de antemano a todos los que lo intentéis.

Comment: Por "tengo un .java" ¿te refieres a un servlet? ¿Estás seguro de que se está ejecutando la parte en la que asignas el atributo? El código que muestras parece correcto.

Comment: Si, disculpa, me refiero a un servelet. Funciona todo bien, porque en un principio usaba esto:


`request.setAttribute("Resultado", matriz);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/resultado.jsp").forward(request,response);`


Y me daba todo correcto, sin embargo me han comunicado que necesitan que lo haga de la otra manera y no me funciona.

Comment: La única diferencia que veo es que el objeto `session` es compartido entre todas las peticiones de la misma sesión web, así que existe la posibilidad de que otro servlet o JSP elimine ese atributo, o que no estés haciendo las llamadas desde la misma sesión. Puedes intentar definir `HttpSessionListener` y `HttpSessionAttributeListener` para hacer log de lo que está pasando en realidad. Ah, y en el JSP ya existe un objeto implícito `session` así que no necesitas hacer `request.getSession()`.

Comment: Solo te comento que los scriptlets, ese código Java dentro del JSP como `<% %>` es un terrible problema. Te recomendaría, en su lugar, usar JSTL para manejar la lógica de la vista.

Comment: Ya me funciona. El problema es que si soy sincero, no se como. Simplemente al día siguiente empecé de 0 y funciono. Mi error fue no guardar nada para compararlo después.